# Google Web Toolkit, RPC ans MSSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, gwt, jakarta-ee, jdbc, gwt-rpc

I implemented google's "Build a sample GWT Application" and "GWT RPC" projects from http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/ its site. I need one more thing; a database connection with my project.

I have to use MSSQL SERVER 2008 for the project, and I downloaded JDBC driver's jar files for MSSQL, referenced them from Java Build Path menu, and put them in the project's war/WEB-INF/lib folder. I don't know how to go on. I also have DB Connection class. I put that class into the server side. It uses 'java.sql' package.

can you help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server side in GWT you can work with Connection as in any other project is not based on the GWT. For example

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
ps = connection.prepareStatement("Select * from Users Us");
resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    //take the field and do something with it. You can take something with construction "resultSet.getInt("Us.id")"
}
```

You can also use for to get data ORM, such as Hibernate.

Comment: I implemented google's StockWatcher RPC codes. It guides me very well. As you said, I created database connection class on the server side. Thank you.